# Case-Shiller Index methodology

Tags: regression, finance

I'm new here, I may be in the wrong forum, not sure.  With a little 'stretch', this can be described as a regression question.

I am trying to find a definitive specification of the index construction methodology for the S&P CoreLogic Case-Shiller Home Price Indices produced by S&P Global – also known simply as Case-Shiller indices.  So of course I go to the document titled "[S&P CoreLogic Case-Shiller Home Price Indices Methodology](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/documents/methodologies/methodology-sp-corelogic-cs-home-price-indices.pdf)", and it is dated November 2021, but I know it's not changed substantially since 2016.  The section "Repeat Sales Methodology" p19-23 describes in detail how it's done.

However the method as described does not match (for example) what YouTube tutorial videos show (e.g., [here](https://youtu.be/dUwWzXVbRHI)) for Case-Shiller, which is basically Bailey et al 1963 using OLS regression on dummy variables.  The methods are pretty different – the "official" one regressing prices on prices using dummy Instrumental Variables, and the index as reciprocals of the coefficients.

I am a little baffled because in my limited experience most people believe Case-Shiller uses Bailey 1963 OLS/WLS. The IV method seems somewhat needlessly inefficient as a 'fix' for stochastic regressors, given that the Bailey regression on dummies does not suffer from this problem. The "official" method is also less flexible for my purposes (which are not really relevant to the question).

Is the S&P method really as described – does anyone know for sure, has anyone replicated it?

Comment: Possibly one of the Quantitative Finance or Economics Stack Exchange sites would be a better fit. Or contact S&P.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica  Thanks for that.  Tried Quantitative Finance, got 26 views in a day but no interaction.  Pity it got disqualified here, where it got 2 upvotes quite fast and it is definitely about regression, applied to a very mainstream investment performance index.  I can't see that S&P are going to contradict their own documentation.  That documentation cites Shiller (1993) Macro Markets which is still in print and I just got a copy. It dismisses Bailey (1963) for heteroscedasticity reasons which other studies in Europe cast doubt on.  Surprised S&P went this route.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question's not *about* regression - a definitive answer as to what model S&P use needn't contain anything of statistical interest. It's rather akin to the questions we get get from time to time asking for data - Statistics deals with data, to be sure, but we need to draw a line between questions pertaining to Statistics & those pertaining to one of the many disciplines to which it's ancillary.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I do take your point. I said at the start that it needed a 'stretch' to make it a question 'about regression'. However it is a main contender for the single regression with most economic consequence anywhere, and S&P is a leading supplier of such indices. The official specification states a reliance on IV and not OLS or GLS.  None of these are niche statistical methods. Quant Finance on stack exchange has returned 37 views to date, but no upvotes or downvotes or comments.  Is this really so niche?  It even attracted some interest in this forum until getting blocked.